# Array of templates skipping a specific template tag adjacent to an embedded element

Tags: javascript, lit-element, lit-html

I have an array of templates:

[Template Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04JLF.png)

The code which generated the array:

```
generate_cell_collection() {

        const templates = this.matrix_data.map((item, index) => {
          var template_frag = [];
          var row = Math.floor(index / this.nrow);
          var col = index % this.ncol;
          var row_length = Math.floor(this.matrix_data.length / this.nrow);
          var cell_indices = '(' + row + ',' + col + ')';
          var updated = false;

          this.cell_collection.set(cell_indices, this.matrix_data[row * row_length + col]);

          if (col === 0) { template_frag.push(html`<tr>`); }

          template_frag.push(html`<cell-display .cell_indices=${cell_indices}
                                                .cell_value=${this.matrix_data[row * row_length + col]}
                                                updated=${updated}></cell-display>`);

          if (col === this.ncol - 1) { template_frag.push(html`</tr>`); }
          return template_frag;

            }).flat();

        return templates;

       }


    render() {

      var templates = this.generate_cell_collection();

      return html`
        <div id=${this.descriptor}>
        <table>
        <tbody>
        ${templates}
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    `;
    }
```

and the code for the embedded element:

```
export class CellDisplay extends LitElement {

  static get properties() {
      return {
        cell_indices: { type: String },
        cell_value: { type: Number },
        updated: { type: Boolean}
      }
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
  return html`
          <td><div id=${this.cell_indices}></div>${this.cell_value}</td>`;

  }

}
```

However in rendering the templates, the template containing the `</tr>` tag is consistently not being incorporated with an additional comment inserted instead.

[Template Rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Vutw.png)

I have attempted to step through the debugger to identify the basis for this without success.  Any suggestions as to why would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is invalid:

```
html`<tr>`
```

lit-html templates are parsed independently, which means they must be well-formed to behave as expected. If you only have the opening of a tag, then it'll be closed by the parser.

Instead, you need to write:

```js
html`<tr>${somethingHere}</tr>`
```